# In How Many Ways to extract youtube videos comments using java or java API?

Tags: java

My requirement is log in to my you tube account its will  show  each video comments and like and dislike details   using java API ?

i searched but i did't get properly
what are the ways to retrieve these information.
Could u please help Me?

Answer (score 1):

**Retrieving comments for a video**

Each video entry contains a  tag, which encapsulates the URL to which you will send API requests to retrieve or append to the list of comments for the video. The sample XML below shows how this URL appears in an API response:

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    ...
    <media:group>
      ...
    </media:group>
    <gd:comments>
      <gd:feedLink
        href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments'/>
    </gd:comments>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Please note, that it is only available in API v2, yet. [Here you can read more](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5046).